# Migrating PHP web app to iOS

Tags: php, iphone

So I've built a web app in PHP that relies heavily on a MySQL database. Now (for user convenience purposes) I'm trying to create the exact same app, just as an iPhone app. Granted, I have no knowledge of Objective-C (just starting to learn it), I wanted to know how to go about this. I know that I'll have to use some kind of intermediary to get Objective-C to connect to the SQL database.

So essentially my questions are: If I've already created the web app as aforementioned, could I use the same DB and tables for the iOS app version as I did for the PHP web version? Also, is there anyway to migrate any code I've created in PHP to iOS (I realize that they are two completely different languages), but I'm just curious as to whether or not I'll have to build the iOS app from 'complete' scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your MySQL database for any purpose because it is just data. The code that will show them will be different though. If you have no knowledge about Objective-C you should consider the web-app approach.

Here are a few helper links.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/referencelibrary/gettingstarted/gs_iphonewebapp/_index.html
http://gigaom.com/2010/02/12/how-to-create-an-iphone-web-app/

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to write an PHP service to talk to your database.

This way you can share this API between your app or `iOS` app or any other type of client app.

The service will be responsible to receive request query the database and send responses in JSON format for example.

So to make things easier, you should not query the database directly from your apps, use a common web service.